# ANTLR - Not able to set defaultErrorHandler to false

Tags: c#, antlr3

I created a simple grammar in ANTLR and everything works ok.

But, when I tried to turn off default error handling, I got an error: illegal option defaultErrorHandler.

```
grammar MyGrammar;
options {
language = CSharp3;
output=AST;
defaultErrorHandler=false;
}
```

Without the line  `defaultErrorHandler=false;` everything works ok, but with this line added to the options I got an error.

I am working in ANTLRWorks version 1.5.2

Am I missing something?

Comment: No answer here, but I'd move to ANTLR4 instead of using the old v3. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ANTLR3, you customize the error display by overriding one or more of these methods:

- `emitErrorMessage()` - determines how error message is displayed
- `displayRecognitionError()` - creates the error message, and calls the above
- `getErrorHeader()`, `getErrorMessage()` - creates the error message for the above

This can be done by either making the parser a subclass of your parser class via `superClass` option, or directly in grammar using `@members` block.

---

If you want to modify how ANTLR recovers from the error, you will need to either override `recover()` or use `@rulecatch` block in grammar.

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think `defaultErrorHandler` would be a valid option? Read [the documentation](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/ANTLR3/pages/2687245/Grammar+options) to see what's allowed.

Comment: This http://www.antlr2.org/doc/options.html#defaultErrorHandler  is where defaultErrorHandler is mentioned, but maybe it is just for older versions of ANTLR

Comment: This is for ANTLR2.